# Configure custom DNS for Public IP Address

Tags: azure, dns, azure-load-balancer, azure-public-ip, azure-dns

i created VM behide Azure Load Balancer. i want to use custom domain to Load Balance Public IP. for example i want to access url like 'xx.mvg.com' instead Load Balance Public IP from internet. how i can do it?

i tried to did followed reference link 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain' but still not working.

Please recommend how to register my domain name i wish, i want map my domain name to my application running on VM behide Azure Load Balancer.

and Azure have service about internet domain registrar?

Answer (score 1):

about your last question - no, Azure have only Azure DNS, which is not a domain registrar, but a DNS as a service.

Easiest way to achieve what you want - assign a dns name to a public ip (called dns label [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-public-ip-address)) and create a CNAME record in your DNS for that DNS name. or just straight up create a A record in your DNS and point it to your public ip.